# What are my errors in the following code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

This is the function:

```
for (i = 0; i <= array.Length; i++) {
      if (array[i].transform.position = 0)
        array.RemoveAt(i);
        print(“Removed element: “ + array[i].name);
      else if (array[i].transform.position > 0)
         array[i].transform.forward = Vector3(1,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Have you actually looked at your compiler's output? i'm sure it would be happy to tell you what your errors are.

Comment: Maybe compiler is sleeping... shhhhhh!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't compare a vector to 0 it needs to be like this

if(myObject.transform.position==Vector3.zero)

and for removing things I'd suggest to include System.Collections.generic lib 
then use Listarray then you can use array.RemoveAt(index);

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a valid question but there is for sure some logic errors :

- First of all i'm not sure there is a `RemoveAt(int index)` for arrays
  (but i'm not a big unityscript user) (there is for List though)
- You should absolutely never (even if some weird languages maybe allow it to you) try to access an object you just deleted... which is what you try to do here :

  ```
  array.RemoveAt(i);
  print(“Removed element: “ + array[i].name);
  ```
- Position is a Vector3 NOT a int or float so you cannot do : `array[i].transform.position = 0`
- You should never use the = (assignment operator) in an if() you should use the == (comparison operator) (because = returns always true when assignment is possible)
- That line is wrong for the same reason as before `array[i].transform.position > 0`
- `array[i].transform.forward = Vector3(1,0,0);` Leaves me wondering because if it was C# i'd try the `new` keyword before Vector3() and i'd prefer floats that way :
- `array[i].transform.forward = new Vector3(1.0F,0,0);` But even there Unity will throw you an error stating that you cannot modify components of Transform without making a copy first i believe...

But nice try :D

Comment: Further, there are no curly braces meaning the `print(“Removed element: “ + array[i].name);` won't be inside the if and it won't know what the `else if` is relating to

Comment: `array[i].transform.forward = new Vector3(1.0F,0,0)` is valid, no warning/error.

Comment: Yep maybe because the array of gameObjects is not referencing GameObjects in the scene/Editor but clones of those which should work